# How can I open a JInternalFrame inside a panel (inside parent) from another child JInternalFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

I have 3 frames, Main (as the parent) and 2 JInternalFrames (F1 and F2 as children). When a button (inside parent) is pressed, I make an instance of F1 and send it as a parameter to `ShowIntrlFrame()` so F1 can be displayed inside `frmContainter`. My question here is, how can I open F2 from F1 and display it on `frmContrainer` (which is in the `Main` frame)?

```
public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame{
        public Main(){
        }

        private void btnOpenFrmActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
                F1 f1 = new F1();
                frmContainer(f1);
        } 
}
```

```
public void ShowIntrlFrame(JInternalFrame f){
        f.setSize(1100, 620);
        f.setLocation(0, 0);
        f.setVisible(true);
        
        frmContainer.removeAll();
        frmContainer.add(f, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frmContainer.revalidate();
        frmContainer.repaint();       
}
```

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Internal Frames](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html). The demo code will show how to create multiple frames. The only difference is the tutorial uses a JMenuItem but you use a JButton. Both components use an ActionListener so the code will be almost the same.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is follow a delegation pattern via [dependency injection](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/a-quick-intro-to-dependency-injection-what-it-is-and-when-to-use-it-7578c84fa88f/).

This is, I would "delegate" the functionality need to generate and show the window to some other class and then "inject" that into the workflow as required

I'd start with a concept of a "window manager"...

```
public interface WindowManager {
    enum Window {
        FIRST, SECOND;
    }
    public void openWindow(Window window);
}
```

At the moment, this is pretty basic and just opens a specified window.  The nice thing about this, is we don't care if it's a `JInternalFrame` or `JFrame` which gets generated, that's not the callers responsibility.

Next, we make a implementation which supports `JDesktopPane`

```
public class DesktopWindowManage implements WindowManager {
    
    private JDesktopPane desktopPane;
    private int initialX = 0;
    private int initialY = 0;

    public DesktopWindowManage(JDesktopPane desktopPane) {
        this.desktopPane = desktopPane;
    }

    public JDesktopPane getDesktopPane() {
        return desktopPane;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void openWindow(Window window) {
        JInternalFrame frame = new JInternalFrame(window.name(), true, true, true, true);
        frame.setContentPane(makeContentFor(window));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(initialX, initialY);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        try {
            frame.setSelected(true);
        } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
        }
        desktopPane.add(frame);
        frame.toFront();
        
        initialX += 20;
        initialY += 20;
    }
    
    protected JPanel makeContentFor(Window window) {
        switch (window) {
            case FIRST: return new FirstPane(this);
            case SECOND: return new SecondPane();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now, important to note, this class is acting as kind of [factory](https://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html), in that it's generating the content view and `JInternalFrame`.  I'd probably consider making a "content factory" which could be injected into this which would then create the content based on the desired destination, but that's probably getting a little more complicated then is required right now.

Now, before you ask, the actual content is based on `JPanel`, for example...

```
public class FirstPane extends JPanel {
    public FirstPane(WindowManager windowManager) {
        setBorder(new EmptyBorder(32, 32, 32, 32));
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = gbc.REMAINDER;
        add(new JLabel("I am first"), gbc);
        
        JButton showSecond = new JButton("Show second");
        showSecond.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                windowManager.openWindow(WindowManager.Window.SECOND);
            }
        });
        add(showSecond, gbc);
    }
}

public class SecondPane extends JPanel {
    
    public SecondPane() {
        setBorder(new EmptyBorder(32, 32, 32, 32));
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(new JLabel("I am second"));
    }
    
}
```

Why?  Because it's a `JPanel` can be added to any container and, generally, we don't care if it's a `JInternalFrame` or `JFrame`.

And finally, some kind of "starting point"....

```
public class MainPane extends JPanel {

    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private JDesktopPane desktopPane;
    
    public MainPane() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JButton open = new JButton("Open");
        desktopPane = new JDesktopPane() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(400, 400);
            }
        };
        
        windowManager = new DesktopWindowManage(desktopPane);
        
        add(open, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(desktopPane);
        
        open.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                windowManager.openWindow(WindowManager.Window.FIRST);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

## Runnable example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new MainPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public interface WindowManager {
        enum Window {
            FIRST, SECOND;
        }
        public void openWindow(Window window);
    }

    public class DesktopWindowManage implements WindowManager {

        private JDesktopPane desktopPane;
        private int initialX = 0;
        private int initialY = 0;

        public DesktopWindowManage(JDesktopPane desktopPane) {
            this.desktopPane = desktopPane;
        }

        public JDesktopPane getDesktopPane() {
            return desktopPane;
        }

        @Override
        public void openWindow(Window window) {
            JInternalFrame frame = new JInternalFrame(window.name(), true, true, true, true);
            frame.setContentPane(makeContentFor(window));
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocation(initialX, initialY);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            try {
                frame.setSelected(true);
            } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
            }
            desktopPane.add(frame);
            frame.toFront();

            initialX += 20;
            initialY += 20;
        }

        protected JPanel makeContentFor(Window window) {
            switch (window) {
                case FIRST: return new FirstPane(this);
                case SECOND: return new SecondPane();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class MainPane extends JPanel {

        private WindowManager windowManager;
        private JDesktopPane desktopPane;

        public MainPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JButton open = new JButton("Open");
            desktopPane = new JDesktopPane() {
                @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return new Dimension(400, 400);
                }
            };

            windowManager = new DesktopWindowManage(desktopPane);

            add(open, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            add(desktopPane);

            open.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    windowManager.openWindow(WindowManager.Window.FIRST);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.dispose();
        }        
    }

    public class FirstPane extends JPanel {
        public FirstPane(WindowManager windowManager) {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(32, 32, 32, 32));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = gbc.REMAINDER;
            add(new JLabel("I am first"), gbc);

            JButton showSecond = new JButton("Show second");
            showSecond.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    windowManager.openWindow(WindowManager.Window.SECOND);
                }
            });
            add(showSecond, gbc);
        }
    }

    public class SecondPane extends JPanel {

        public SecondPane() {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(32, 32, 32, 32));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(new JLabel("I am second"));
        }

    }
}
```

### But wait, there's more...

Currently, if you tap "Open" or "Show second" multiple times, you get a bunch of new windows.  This may or may not be desirable, but could be easily fixed via the `WindowManager`, in fact, you could create different `WindowManager`s based on your needs, for example...

```
public class DesktopWindowManage implements WindowManager {

    private JDesktopPane desktopPane;
    private int initialX = 0;
    private int initialY = 0;

    private Map<Window, JInternalFrame> windowCache = new HashMap<>();

    public DesktopWindowManage(JDesktopPane desktopPane) {
        this.desktopPane = desktopPane;
    }

    public JDesktopPane getDesktopPane() {
        return desktopPane;
    }

    @Override
    public void openWindow(Window window) {
        JInternalFrame frame = windowCache.get(window);
        if (frame == null) {
            frame = new JInternalFrame(window.name(), true, true, true, true);
            frame.setContentPane(makeContentFor(window));
            windowCache.put(window, frame);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocation(initialX, initialY);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            desktopPane.add(frame);
            initialX += 20;
            initialY += 20;
        }
        try {
            frame.setSelected(true);
        } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
        }
        frame.toFront();
    }

    protected JPanel makeContentFor(Window window) {
        switch (window) {
            case FIRST:
                return new FirstPane(this);
            case SECOND:
                return new SecondPane();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```